# I cannot start ng serve --open command in Angular 11

Tags: angular-cli

I start application using ng serve --o successfully so far. But now I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\node_modules'

The log file:

```
    [error] Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'D:\node_modules'
    at Object.realpathSync (fs.js:1615:7)
    at D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:44:35
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.getStylesConfig (D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\styles.js:35:76)
    at D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:91:23
    at generateWebpackConfig (D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:45:49)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async generateBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:136:20)
    at async Object.generateI18nBrowserWebpackConfigFromContext (D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\utils\webpack-browser-config.js:77:20)
    at async setup (D:\Development\AlishAngular\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\dev-server\index.js:87:47)
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: @BojanKogoj yes I did,, still same problem